# How to change type from word to dword on assembly?

Tags: assembly

I have an assembly program which sort an word array.
But i must change program to sort dword array. Can you help me?

I tried to just switch to 32-bit e** registers but it broke my program. (i guess i also must change a shift but i am not sure) 
Also i tried to change a shift from 2 to 4 but it also did not work. (I also puzzled why)

Code of my assembly program:

```
.MODEL small
STACK SEGMENT PARA STACK 'stack' 
    DW 100h DUP(?)
STACK ENDS

DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'data'
    mas DW 5, -2, -1, 1, 18, -6, 5, 6, -3, -20, -17, 7, 0 
    res DW 13 DUP(0) 
    counter DW 22 
    maxsize EQU $-mas
    one EQU 2

DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'code'
    ASSUME CS: CODE, DS: DATA, SS: STACK
.486    
START:
    MOV AX, DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    lea DI, offset mas
    LEA BX,mas
    MOV CX,counter
    DEC CX
    MOV SI,0          
  @@ForI:
    MOV DI,counter          
    DEC DI
    SHL DI,1
  @@ForJ:             
    MOV AX,[BX+DI-one]  
    NOT AX
    AND AX,[BX+DI]
    JNS @@NextJ       
    XCHG AX,[BX+DI]   
    XCHG AX,[BX+DI-one] 
    XCHG AX,[BX+DI]   
  @@NextJ:
    SUB DI,one         
    CMP DI,SI         
    JA @@ForJ
    ADD SI,one          
    LOOP @@ForI
second:
    xor cx, cx
    xor bx, bx
sum:
    mov dx, [bx]
    mov si, bx
    mov ax, dx
    xor dx, dx
    mov bx, one
    div bx

    xor bx, bx 
    mov bx, si

    cmp dx, 01h
    jl slozh

continue:
    mov ax, bx
    cmp ax, counter
    jg last

    add bx, one
    jmp sum

slozh:
    add cx, [bx]
    jmp continue

last:
    xor bx, bx
    xor bp, bp

check:
    mov dx, [bx]
    cmp dx, 0
    JE EXIT
    cmp dx, cx
    jg addel

    cmp bx, counter-1
    jg EXIT
    add bx, one

    jmp check

addel:
    mov res[bp], dx
    add bp, one
    add bx, one
    jmp check
EXIT:
    MOV EAX, 4c00h
    INT 21h
end START
```

Comment: This look like 16bit code, designed to run under DOS.  DOS didn't support 32bit executables, which means you can't use 32bit registers (eax, etc).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd the 16b real mode on 80386+ CPU does allow limited usage of 32 bit instructions (through `66` size prefix opcode byte).

Comment: You must stop guessing, and just figuring out what you want. If you want to sort dwords, you need first dword array, so far I see word array. Then you need to change all addressing to be *4, not *2. Then all the value fetch+compare+store need to work with 32b values. There's no point to post working 16b code (unless you expect somebody to write the code for you), show what you tried, and identify in debugger what is not working (actually maybe you will be able some problems yourself, once you will be able to identify what the problem exactly is). And `div` by `2`? Really?

Comment: `one EQU 2` Is this intended to be intentionally confusing?  If it's supposed to be the width of an element, call it `element_size` or something.  Also, using `xchg` with memory to swap is horrible (even worse than using `div` instead of a right shift by 1.)  It has an implicit `lock` prefix so it's very slow.  Load the other value into `dx` or somethig, then store both.